# МЕТОДЫ ДОЧЕРНЕГО КЛАССА

Tags: javascript

Метод isBlacklisted(email) для проверки почты в чёрном списке. Метод должен проверять наличие значения параметра email в массиве хранящемся в свойстве blacklistedEmails и возвращать true или false, что я делаю не так?

```
class User {
  email;

  constructor(email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  get email() {
    return this.email;
  }

  set email(newEmail) {
    this.email = newEmail;
  }
}
class Admin extends User {
 
 blacklistedEmails=[];

blacklist(email){
this.blacklistedEmails.push(email)
};

*isBlacklisted(email){
this.blacklistedEmails.includes(email)
};*

  static AccessLevel = {
    BASIC: "basic",
    SUPERUSER: "superuser",
  };

  constructor({ email, accessLevel }) {
    super(email);
    this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
  }


}

const mango = new Admin({
  email: "mango@mail.com",
  accessLevel: Admin.AccessLevel.SUPERUSER,
});

console.log(mango.email); // "mango@mail.com"
console.log(mango.accessLevel); // "superuser"

mango.blacklist("poly@mail.com");
console.log(mango.blacklistedEmails); // ["poly@mail.com"]
console.log(mango.isBlacklisted("mango@mail.com")); // false
console.log(mango.isBlacklisted("poly@mail.com")); // true
```

Comment: ....А что не так?

Comment: Для того, чтобы понимать что где не так, применяют часто отладку (см. ссылку в шапке вопроса)..... если после всех тщетных попыток не удастся понять что не так  и если никто лишнего тут не напишет - подскажу где ошибка.......но лучше логически рассуди...... что у тебя должно возвращаться и что возвращается.....и проверь отладчиком те самые места, для надёжности

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо=)